# What is a best known algorithm for finding diameter of undirected graph?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, reference-request, efficiency

What is best (in terms of time complexity) known algorithm (approximate or exact) for finding diameter of a large undirected graph?

The diameter is defined as longest of shortest paths between any two nodes.

I know that naive solution takes O(nm) steps and is basically taking pairs of all vertices and finds distances between them.

This is very slow for large graphs, 2^20 nodes or more.

An example graph

http://snap.stanford.edu/data/com-Orkut.html

Comment: Especially when you also care about approximate methods, *best in what sense*?

Comment: Best in terms of time complexity

Comment: If you're willing to settle for a 2-approximation, you can run BFS from an arbitrary node.

Comment: How would 2 approximation work in this case? Looks like it would give different answer in each case.

Comment: @RB It is a **worst-case** 2-approximation. It will return a value between the actual diameter and 2x the actual diameter.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden but of course this approach cannot output a value which is *higher* than the real diameter. Therefore, the above 2-approximation returns a value between the diameter and 0.5x the actual diameter.

Comment: There are several studies about this topic. For example, I suggest this paper. http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1455266